# Filter DataView with List<string> or string[]

Tags: .net, generics, c#-4.0, dataview

I want to apply a rowfilter on dataview which should work on List. Below is the code i have written so far with no luck.

> gets all the tags with <% %> symbols from a source string

```
string src = "<%Borrower Name%>|<%Dealer Number%>|<%Application Number%>|【<%Asset Make Description%>】尊敬的经销商：您提交的编号<%Application Number%>客户<%Borrower Name%>的申请已拒绝。";

MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(src, @"\<%([^%>]*)\%>");

List<string> lstnew = matches.Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Value).ToList();

DataSet dstokens = new DataSet();

ReadTokensData(dstokens, null);
```

> here comes the filtering part, i want to filter the data table based
>   on values in the list, doing this with string[] is also acceptable for me

```
dstokens.Tables["TOKENS_DATA"].DefaultView.RowFilter = "TOKEN_CAPTION IN (" + lstnew + ")";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This Out

Assuming That dtAllUsers Data Table Has Data In it. We Can Filter The Data From dtAllUsers's Data Table As Follows.

UserName = DataTable's Column Where You Want To Search With

txt_SearchByUser.Text = Texts That You Want To Search In UserName Column

dgv_All_Users =  Is A DataGridView

```
DataView DV = new DataView(dtAllUsers);

DV.RowFilter = string.Format("UserName Like '%{0}%'",txt_SearchByUser.Text);

dgv_All_Users.DataSource = DV;
```

Comment: but this solution only filters the datatable with a single value, my problem is that i have multiple values in the List<string>, so i want to apply filtering on the basis of multiple list items.

Comment: in that case try dtAllUsers.Select( Your Conditions) method

Answer (score 0):

Breaking down your code, it would result as;

```
WHERE TOEKN_CAPTION IN (<%BorrowerName%>,<%DealerNumber%>,<%AppNumber%>,etc)
```

Where as you want

```
WHERE TOEKN_CAPTION IN ('BorrowerName','DealerNumber','AppNumber',etc)
```

Change your Linq statement to the below

```
List<string> lstnew = matches.Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Groups[1].Value).ToList();
```

Comment: i actually want to apply filtering on dataview. list doesnt seem to work. is there any way around?

Comment: Use DataView.RowFilter for that. you can check it on MSDN Help https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.rowfilter(v=vs.110).aspx. However in the end, if your values in the DB are VALUE and not <%VALUE%>, then the filter will still fail with the existing code and not retrieve anything back.